# Most effecient way to return a continuous range where all values match a target in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have column that has a list of month and year combinations in excel. I'm trying to optimize a index match formula and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to return the range of values that match a specific date value than what i was doing.

So for example: 20192 in column F starts at F22:F40 so i'd just like to return that. I should note each date/month combo only appears 1x throughout the column so 20192 will start only one place and be consecutive until it ends and will not appear again in the dataset.

The data is pasted below:

```
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+------------------+--------+
|   Date    | Contract |    OI    |   COD    | Days Till Expiry |  code  |
+-----------+----------+----------+----------+------------------+--------+
| 3-Jan-19  | FEB      | 378,871  | (2,673)  |               28 |  20191 |
| 4-Jan-19  | FEB      | 367,400  | (11,471) |               27 |  20191 |
| 7-Jan-19  | FEB      | 361,363  | (6,037)  |               24 |  20191 |
| 8-Jan-19  | FEB      | 329,416  | (31,947) |               23 |  20191 |
| 9-Jan-19  | FEB      | 290,508  | (38,908) |               22 |  20191 |
| 10-Jan-19 | FEB      | 260,311  | (30,197) |               21 |  20191 |
| 11-Jan-19 | FEB      | 216,583  | (43,728) |               20 |  20191 |
| 14-Jan-19 | FEB      | 176,807  | (39,776) |               17 |  20191 |
| 15-Jan-19 | FEB      | 145,033  | (31,774) |               16 |  20191 |
| 16-Jan-19 | FEB      | 89,777   | (55,256) |               15 |  20191 |
| 17-Jan-19 | FEB      | 61,293   | (28,484) |               14 |  20191 |
| 18-Jan-19 | FEB      | 25,682   | (35,611) |               13 |  20191 |
| 22-Jan-19 | MAR      | 499,043  | (6,558)  |                9 |  20191 |
| 23-Jan-19 | MAR      | 496,877  | (2,166)  |                8 |  20191 |
| 24-Jan-19 | MAR      | 481,966  | (14,911) |                7 |  20191 |
| 25-Jan-19 | MAR      | 471,888  | (10,078) |                6 |  20191 |
| 28-Jan-19 | MAR      | 469,447  | (2,441)  |                3 |  20191 |
| 29-Jan-19 | MAR      | 464,251  | (5,196)  |                2 |  20191 |
| 30-Jan-19 | MAR      | 466,044  | 1,793    |                1 |  20191 |
| 31-Jan-19 | MAR      | 463,779  | (2,265)  |               28 |  20191 |
| 1-Feb-19  | MAR      | 457,940  | (5,839)  |               27 |  20192 |
| 4-Feb-19  | MAR      | 441,710  | (16,230) |               24 |  20192 |
| 5-Feb-19  | MAR      | 431,584  | (10,126) |               23 |  20192 |
| 6-Feb-19  | MAR      | 413,688  | (17,896) |               22 |  20192 |
| 7-Feb-19  | MAR      | 371,226  | (42,462) |               21 |  20192 |
| 8-Feb-19  | MAR      | 318,986  | (52,240) |               20 |  20192 |
| 11-Feb-19 | MAR      | 264,681  | (54,305) |               17 |  20192 |
| 12-Feb-19 | MAR      | 223,779  | (40,902) |               16 |  20192 |
| 13-Feb-19 | MAR      | 163,621  | (60,158) |               15 |  20192 |
| 14-Feb-19 | MAR      | 109,346  | (54,275) |               14 |  20192 |
| 15-Feb-19 | MAR      | 74,706   | (34,640) |               13 |  20192 |
| 19-Feb-19 | MAR      | 29,785   | (44,921) |                9 |  20192 |
| 20-Feb-19 | APR      | 407,691  | 8,288    |                8 |  20192 |
| 21-Feb-19 | APR      | 400,292  | (7,399)  |                7 |  20192 |
| 22-Feb-19 | APR      | 399,406  | (886)    |                6 |  20192 |
| 25-Feb-19 | APR      | 387,301  | (12,105) |                3 |  20192 |
| 26-Feb-19 | APR      | 382,166  | (5,135)  |                2 |  20192 |
| 27-Feb-19 | APR      | 383,252  | 1,086    |                1 |  20192 |
| 28-Feb-19 | APR      | 377,617  | (5,635)  |               29 |  20192 |
| 1-Mar-19  | APR      | 368,105  | (9,512)  |               28 |  20193 |
| 4-Mar-19  | APR      | 358,824  | (9,281)  |               25 |  20193 |
| 5-Mar-19  | APR      | 353,287  | (5,537)  |               24 |  20193 |
| 6-Mar-19  | APR      | 332,570  | (20,717) |               23 |  20193 |
| 7-Mar-19  | APR      | 294,866  | (37,704) |               22 |  20193 |
| 8-Mar-19  | APR      | 252,613  | (42,253) |               21 |  20193 |
| 11-Mar-19 | APR      | 215,862  | (36,751) |               18 |  20193 |
| 12-Mar-19 | APR      | 184,451  | (31,411) |               17 |  20193 |
| 13-Mar-19 | APR      | 161,079  | (23,372) |               16 |  20193 |
| 14-Mar-19 | APR      | 134,939  | (26,140) |               15 |  20193 |
| 15-Mar-19 | APR      | 98,719   | (36,220) |               14 |  20193 |
| 18-Mar-19 | APR      | 67,480   | (31,239) |               11 |  20193 |
| 19-Mar-19 | APR      | 18,770   | (48,710) |               10 |  20193 |
| 20-Mar-19 | MAY      | 435,389  | (301)    |                9 |  20193 |
| 21-Mar-19 | MAY      | 434,375  | (1,014)  |                8 |  20193 |
| 22-Mar-19 | MAY      | 426,723  | (7,652)  |                7 |  20193 |
| 25-Mar-19 | MAY      | 423,515  | (3,208)  |                4 |  20193 |
| 26-Mar-19 | MAY      | 422,471  | (1,044)  |                3 |  20193 |
| 27-Mar-19 | MAY      | 409,365  | (13,106) |                2 |  20193 |
| 28-Mar-19 | MAY      | 401,827  | (7,538)  |                1 |  20193 |
| 29-Mar-19 | MAY      | 403,676  | 1,849    |               32 |  20193 |
| 1-Apr-19  | MAY      | 405,918  | 2,242    |               29 |  20194 |
| 2-Apr-19  | MAY      | 391,777  | (14,141) |               28 |  20194 |
| 3-Apr-19  | MAY      | 374,802  | (16,975) |               27 |  20194 |
| 4-Apr-19  | MAY      | 361,966  | (12,836) |               26 |  20194 |
| 5-Apr-19  | MAY      | 346,628  | (15,338) |               25 |  20194 |
| 8-Apr-19  | MAY      | 318,369  | (28,259) |               22 |  20194 |
| 9-Apr-19  | MAY      | 280,173  | (38,196) |               21 |  20194 |
| 10-Apr-19 | MAY      | 257,042  | (23,131) |               20 |  20194 |
| 11-Apr-19 | MAY      | 218,311  | (38,731) |               19 |  20194 |
| 12-Apr-19 | MAY      | 196,720  | (21,591) |               18 |  20194 |
| 15-Apr-19 | MAY      | 162,601  | (34,119) |               15 |  20194 |
| 16-Apr-19 | MAY      | 98,193   | (64,408) |               14 |  20194 |
| 17-Apr-19 | MAY      | 72,280   | (25,913) |               13 |  20194 |
| 18-Apr-19 | MAY      | 22,036   | (50,244) |               12 |  20194 |
| 22-Apr-19 | JUN      | 477,250  | 16,318   |                8 |  20194 |
| 23-Apr-19 | JUN      | 473,277  | (3,973)  |                7 |  20194 |
| 24-Apr-19 | JUN      | 473,594  | 317      |                6 |  20194 |
| 25-Apr-19 | JUN      | 459,817  | (13,777) |                5 |  20194 |
| 26-Apr-19 | JUN      | 456,552  | (3,265)  |                4 |  20194 |
| 29-Apr-19 | JUN      | 446,583  | (9,969)  |                1 |  20194 |
| 30-Apr-19 | JUN      | 439,249  | (7,334)  |               31 |  20194 |
| 1-May-19  | JUN      | 431,230  | (8,019)  |               30 |  20195 |
| 2-May-19  | JUN      | 420,813  | (10,417) |               29 |  20195 |
| 3-May-19  | JUN      | 394,652  | (26,161) |               28 |  20195 |
| 6-May-19  | JUN      | 384,049  | (10,603) |               25 |  20195 |
| 7-May-19  | JUN      | 347,698  | (36,351) |               24 |  20195 |
| 8-May-19  | JUN      | 315,442  | (32,256) |               23 |  20195 |
| 9-May-19  | JUN      | 292,022  | (23,420) |               22 |  20195 |
| 10-May-19 | JUN      | 261,381  | (30,641) |               21 |  20195 |
| 13-May-19 | JUN      | 229,525  | (31,856) |               18 |  20195 |
| 14-May-19 | JUN      | 203,905  | (25,620) |               17 |  20195 |
| 15-May-19 | JUN      | 166,034  | (37,871) |               16 |  20195 |
| 16-May-19 | JUN      | 98,367   | (67,667) |               15 |  20195 |
| 17-May-19 | JUN      | 66,762   | (31,605) |               14 |  20195 |
| 20-May-19 | JUN      | 20,690   | (46,072) |               11 |  20195 |
| 21-May-19 | JUL      | 441,614  | (5,739)  |               10 |  20195 |
| 22-May-19 | JUL      | 441,633  | 19       |                9 |  20195 |
| 23-May-19 | JUL      | 438,307  | (3,326)  |                8 |  20195 |
| 24-May-19 | JUL      | 427,918  | (10,389) |                7 |  20195 |
| 28-May-19 | JUL      | 412,018  | (15,900) |                3 |  20195 |
| 29-May-19 | JUL      | 382,277  | (29,741) |                2 |  20195 |
| 30-May-19 | JUL      | 376,374  | (5,903)  |                1 |  20195 |
| 31-May-19 | JUL      | 368,466  | (7,908)  |               28 |  20195 |
| 3-Jun-19  | JUL      | 366,193  | (2,273)  |               25 |  20196 |
| 4-Jun-19  | JUL      | 363,046  | (3,147)  |               24 |  20196 |
| 5-Jun-19  | JUL      | 362,201  | (845)    |               23 |  20196 |
| 6-Jun-19  | JUL      | 343,970  | (18,231) |               22 |  20196 |
| 7-Jun-19  | JUL      | 308,942  | (35,028) |               21 |  20196 |
| 10-Jun-19 | JUL      | 272,110  | (36,832) |               18 |  20196 |
| 11-Jun-19 | JUL      | 237,203  | (34,907) |               17 |  20196 |
| 12-Jun-19 | JUL      | 203,403  | (33,800) |               16 |  20196 |
| 13-Jun-19 | JUL      | 157,857  | (45,546) |               15 |  20196 |
| 14-Jun-19 | JUL      | 128,496  | (29,361) |               14 |  20196 |
| 17-Jun-19 | JUL      | 79,872   | (48,624) |               11 |  20196 |
| 18-Jun-19 | JUL      | 54,119   | (25,753) |               10 |  20196 |
| 19-Jun-19 | JUL      | 21,321   | (32,798) |                9 |  20196 |
| 20-Jun-19 | AUG      | 347,579  | 4,288    |                8 |  20196 |
| 21-Jun-19 | AUG      | 345,680  | (1,899)  |                7 |  20196 |
| 24-Jun-19 | AUG      | 341,183  | (4,497)  |                4 |  20196 |
| 25-Jun-19 | AUG      | 338,117  | (3,066)  |                3 |  20196 |
| 26-Jun-19 | AUG      | 338,300  | 183      |                2 |  20196 |
| 27-Jun-19 | AUG      | 334,543  | (3,757)  |                1 |  20196 |
| 28-Jun-19 | AUG      | 328,837  | (5,706)  |               33 |  20196 |
| 1-Jul-19  | AUG      | 319,323  | (9,514)  |               30 |  20197 |
| 2-Jul-19  | AUG      | 313,008  | (6,315)  |               29 |  20197 |
| 3-Jul-19  | AUG      | 299,915  | (13,093) |               28 |  20197 |
| 5-Jul-19  | AUG      | 289,164  | (10,751) |               26 |  20197 |
| 8-Jul-19  | AUG      | 262,191  | (26,973) |               23 |  20197 |
| 9-Jul-19  | AUG      | 234,613  | (27,578) |               22 |  20197 |
| 10-Jul-19 | AUG      | 215,505  | (19,108) |               21 |  20197 |
| 11-Jul-19 | AUG      | 199,666  | (15,839) |               20 |  20197 |
| 12-Jul-19 | AUG      | 179,768  | (19,898) |               19 |  20197 |
| 15-Jul-19 | AUG      | 147,999  | (31,769) |               16 |  20197 |
| 16-Jul-19 | AUG      | 119,793  | (28,206) |               15 |  20197 |
| 17-Jul-19 | AUG      | 83,809   | (35,984) |               14 |  20197 |
| 18-Jul-19 | AUG      | 55,908   | (27,901) |               13 |  20197 |
| 19-Jul-19 | AUG      | 19,557   | (36,351) |               12 |  20197 |
| 22-Jul-19 | SEP      | 438,301  | 391      |                9 |  20197 |
| 23-Jul-19 | SEP      | 431,404  | (6,897)  |                8 |  20197 |
| 24-Jul-19 | SEP      | 421,203  | (10,201) |                7 |  20197 |
| 25-Jul-19 | SEP      | 417,324  | (3,879)  |                6 |  20197 |
| 26-Jul-19 | SEP      | 410,680  | (6,644)  |                5 |  20197 |
| 29-Jul-19 | SEP      | 411,795  | 1,115    |                2 |  20197 |
| 30-Jul-19 | SEP      | 406,009  | (5,786)  |                1 |  20197 |
| 31-Jul-19 | SEP      | 402,392  | (3,617)  |               30 |  20197 |
| 1-Aug-19  | SEP      | 403,715  | 1,323    |               29 |  20198 |
| 2-Aug-19  | SEP      | 399,849  | (3,866)  |               28 |  20198 |
| 5-Aug-19  | SEP      | 384,410  | (15,439) |               25 |  20198 |
| 6-Aug-19  | SEP      | 381,492  | (2,918)  |               24 |  20198 |
| 7-Aug-19  | SEP      | 344,560  | (36,932) |               23 |  20198 |
| 8-Aug-19  | SEP      | 301,000  | (43,560) |               22 |  20198 |
| 9-Aug-19  | SEP      | 266,871  | (34,129) |               21 |  20198 |
| 12-Aug-19 | SEP      | 227,125  | (39,746) |               18 |  20198 |
| 13-Aug-19 | SEP      | 174,139  | (52,986) |               17 |  20198 |
| 14-Aug-19 | SEP      | 137,250  | (36,889) |               16 |  20198 |
| 15-Aug-19 | SEP      | 100,019  | (37,231) |               15 |  20198 |
| 16-Aug-19 | SEP      | 82,935   | (17,084) |               14 |  20198 |
| 19-Aug-19 | SEP      | 34,638   | (48,297) |               11 |  20198 |
| 20-Aug-19 | OCT      | 369,434  | (13,140) |               10 |  20198 |
| 21-Aug-19 | OCT      | 366,408  | (3,026)  |                9 |  20198 |
| 22-Aug-19 | OCT      | 361,189  | (5,219)  |                8 |  20198 |
| 23-Aug-19 | OCT      | 359,507  | (1,682)  |                7 |  20198 |
| 26-Aug-19 | OCT      | 362,457  | 2,950    |                4 |  20198 |
| 27-Aug-19 | OCT      | 369,335  | 6,878    |                3 |  20198 |
| 28-Aug-19 | OCT      | 373,402  | 4,067    |                2 |  20198 |
| 29-Aug-19 | OCT      | 370,192  | (3,210)  |                1 |  20198 |
| 30-Aug-19 | OCT      | 372,871  | 2,679    |               31 |  20198 |
| 3-Sep-19  | OCT      | 370,141  | (2,730)  |               27 |  20199 |
| 4-Sep-19  | OCT      | 351,755  | (18,386) |               26 |  20199 |
| 5-Sep-19  | OCT      | 319,489  | (32,266) |               25 |  20199 |
| 6-Sep-19  | OCT      | 299,951  | (19,538) |               24 |  20199 |
| 9-Sep-19  | OCT      | 265,327  | (34,624) |               21 |  20199 |
| 10-Sep-19 | OCT      | 227,421  | (37,906) |               20 |  20199 |
| 11-Sep-19 | OCT      | 191,570  | (35,851) |               19 |  20199 |
| 12-Sep-19 | OCT      | 159,934  | (31,636) |               18 |  20199 |
| 13-Sep-19 | OCT      | 138,296  | (21,638) |               17 |  20199 |
| 16-Sep-19 | OCT      | 80,041   | (58,255) |               14 |  20199 |
| 17-Sep-19 | OCT      | 59,406   | (20,635) |               13 |  20199 |
| 18-Sep-19 | OCT      | 20,475   | (38,931) |               12 |  20199 |
| 19-Sep-19 | NOV      | 412,945  | 31,478   |               11 |  20199 |
| 20-Sep-19 | NOV      | 411,387  | (1,558)  |               10 |  20199 |
| 23-Sep-19 | NOV      | 406,079  | (5,308)  |                7 |  20199 |
| 24-Sep-19 | NOV      | 404,106  | (1,973)  |                6 |  20199 |
| 25-Sep-19 | NOV      | 390,178  | (13,928) |                5 |  20199 |
| 26-Sep-19 | NOV      | 384,036  | (6,142)  |                4 |  20199 |
| 27-Sep-19 | NOV      | 380,790  | (3,246)  |                3 |  20199 |
| 30-Sep-19 | NOV      | 384,034  | 3,244    |               31 |  20199 |
| 1-Oct-19  | NOV      | 385,741  | 1,707    |               30 | 201910 |
| 2-Oct-19  | NOV      | 387,010  | 1,269    |               29 | 201910 |
| 3-Oct-19  | NOV      | 391,826  | 4,816    |               28 | 201910 |
| 4-Oct-19  | NOV      | 388,735  | (3,091)  |               27 | 201910 |
| 7-Oct-19  | NOV      | 353,392  | (35,343) |               24 | 201910 |
| 8-Oct-19  | NOV      | 303,430  | (49,962) |               23 | 201910 |
| 9-Oct-19  | NOV      | 258,642  | (44,788) |               22 | 201910 |
| 10-Oct-19 | NOV      | 224,022  | (34,620) |               21 | 201910 |
| 11-Oct-19 | NOV      | 182,895  | (41,127) |               20 | 201910 |
| 14-Oct-19 | NOV      | 167,983  | (14,912) |               17 | 201910 |
| 15-Oct-19 | NOV      | 147,337  | (20,646) |               16 | 201910 |
| 16-Oct-19 | NOV      | 121,704  | (25,633) |               15 | 201910 |
| 17-Oct-19 | NOV      | 79,987   | (41,717) |               14 | 201910 |
| 18-Oct-19 | NOV      | 54,642   | (25,345) |               13 | 201910 |
| 21-Oct-19 | NOV      | 31,545   | (23,097) |               10 | 201910 |
| 22-Oct-19 | DEC      | 455,595  | 6,296    |                9 | 201910 |
| 23-Oct-19 | DEC      | 449,370  | (6,225)  |                8 | 201910 |
| 24-Oct-19 | DEC      | 444,100  | (5,270)  |                7 | 201910 |
| 25-Oct-19 | DEC      | 443,839  | (261)    |                6 | 201910 |
| 28-Oct-19 | DEC      | 435,704  | (8,135)  |                3 | 201910 |
| 29-Oct-19 | DEC      | 426,782  | (8,922)  |                2 | 201910 |
| 30-Oct-19 | DEC      | 412,326  | (14,456) |                1 | 201910 |
| 31-Oct-19 | DEC      | 404,468  | (7,858)  |               29 | 201910 |
| 5-Nov-19  | DEC      | 396,111  | (8,357)  |               24 | 201911 |
| 6-Nov-19  | DEC      | 370,659  | (25,452) |               23 | 201911 |
| 7-Nov-19  | DEC      | 352,623  | (18,036) |               22 | 201911 |
| 8-Nov-19  | DEC      | 317,524  | (35,099) |               21 | 201911 |
| 11-Nov-19 | DEC      | 280,522  | (37,002) |               18 | 201911 |
| 12-Nov-19 | DEC      | 223,814  | (56,708) |               17 | 201911 |
| 13-Nov-19 | DEC      | 195,205  | (28,609) |               16 | 201911 |
| 14-Nov-19 | DEC      | 152,910  | (42,295) |               15 | 201911 |
| 15-Nov-19 | DEC      | 99,745   | (53,165) |               14 | 201911 |
| 18-Nov-19 | DEC      | 67,327   | (32,418) |               11 | 201911 |
| 19-Nov-19 | DEC      | 23,223   | (44,104) |               10 | 201911 |
| 20-Nov-19 | JAN      | 456,531  | (14,092) |                9 | 201911 |
```

+-----------+----------+----------+----------+------------------+--------+

[image]

---

**My Current Inefficient Method:**

---

I find the first instance of 20122 by using:

```
=MATCH('Sheet1 (2)'!E3,Sheet1!AP:AP,0)
```

I find the last instance by using:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(Sheet1!AP:AP)*(Sheet1!AP:AP='Sheet1 (2)'!$E$3)))
```

Then I create the range with `indirect()`

```
INDIRECT("Sheet1!AY"&MATCH('Sheet1 (2)'!$E$3,Sheet1!AP:AP,0)&":AY"&SUMPRODUCT(MAX(ROW(Sheet1!AP:AP)*(Sheet1!AP:AP='Sheet1 (2)'!$E$3))))
```

Just thinking there has to be a better way to do this. Unfortunately this is just the first small step in a larger problem so the formula gets convoluted very very quickly.

Comment: If anything, indirect will be volatile, so try to avoid it. You'd rather build your range through index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the range use INDEX/MATCH with COUNTIF:

```
INDEX(Sheet1!AY:AY,MATCH('Sheet1 (2)'!E3,Sheet1!AP:AP,0)):INDEX(Sheet1!AY:AY,MATCH('Sheet1 (2)'!E3,Sheet1!AP:AP,0)+COUNTIF(Sheet1!AP:AP,'Sheet1 (2)'!E3)-1)
```

---

Depending on what you are going to do with the data then one can use the new dynamic array formulas(currently only available in Office 365 insiders)

```
FILTER(Sheet1!AY:AY,Sheet1!AP:AP='Sheet1 (2)'!E3)
```

This will return an array of the values that meet that criteria.

Comment: this use of layering index is indeed a way more efficient approach to what I was doing. Esp with the added countif on top of that.Thank you!